# C++ include header file problems

Tags: c++, c

I have two header files named Secure.h and FileMgt.h. To encrypt the File while saving i use Secure.h in FileMgt.h and in FileMgt.h i have declared some structure which is needed by Secure.h.The FileMgt.h is again include in another file called ElecB.h. I have used header guards in all the Files. The Problem is FileMgt.h is First included in ElecB.h. Since this file is already included in ElecB.h. Now its not including again in Secure.h.
Please give me Solution for this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Smells of classical circular dependency problems.

Comment: Maybe this thread will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-circular-dependencies-in-c

Comment: create a separate header file and place structure in that and include it in both Secure.h and FileMgt.h .

Comment: Its better to use forward declaration instead of including a header file in a header files.

Comment: Forward declaration can used only when a pointer of structure has been used otherwise need the complete declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the structure in a third header file (with include guards) and include it in both Secure.h and FileMgt.h